# List excel pivot items of the second row field (multiple row fields) given a particular pivot item in the first row field

Tags: vba, excel

I searched a long time for this, but still inconclusive. Say I have a pivot table with 2 row labels and 1 data variable looking like:

```
Rowlabel1 Rowlabel2 Sum of value
   a          A          1
              B          2
              C          3
   d          D          4
   e          E          5
```

I want to be able to list the pivot items of `Rowlabel2` given a particular `Rowlabel1`, to get `"A"" B" "C"` in loop, then concat into `"ABC"`. Whatever I try, it only outputs all of the pivot items, `"ABCDE"`.

Since the real data is more complex, it is not possible to do it manually. It also have 3 row labels rather than 2 labels.

Don't know if it would help but the solution can also make use of the values. For example, return the `Rowlabel2` items whose value `<= 3` when "`letter`" is `"a"`.

Thanks for any input!!

Comment: can you use the pivot table as a regular table, and get the data that way with values? This wouldnt work if the pivotitem is collapsed though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub getPiv()

Dim piv As PivotTable

'change this to whatever range and sheet names your pivottable is
Set piv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SecondTable_Output").Range("A3").PivotTable

Dim r As Range
Dim dr As PivotItem

'this captures your first entry in rowlabel1 - change as necessary
Set dr = piv.PivotFields(1).PivotItems(1)

Dim str As String
str = ""

'the macro won't work if the item is collapsed, so we set showDetail to true to expand it
If dr.ShowDetail = False Then
    dr.ShowDetail = True
End If

With dr
    'address what seems to be a bug(??) where if there are more than one data value columns,
    'the datarange appears to shift one row down
    If .DataRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        'here we shift back from the datarange to the 2nd column of the pivottable
        Set r = .DataRange.Offset(-1, -(.DataRange.Cells(1, 1).Column - 2))
    Else
        'here we shift back from the datarange to the 2nd column of the pivottable
        Set r = .DataRange.Offset(0, -(.DataRange.Cells(1, 1).Column - 2))
    End If
End With

'delete as necessary
r.Select

'obtain the string of cell values from the range
For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    str = str & " " & r.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
str = Trim(str)
MsgBox str

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark! It resolved the problem perfectly! The downshifting could be due to subtotal or style of the pivot table, but the solution is great

Comment: Okay, in my project since I have 3 row labels, say, rowlabel0, I am having trouble pinpointing to the datarange of specific rowlabel1 under a specific rowlabel0

Comment: The above issue solved by intersecting two or more ranges

Comment: Hey glad it worked for you :-) Can you accept my answer?