# How to loop through each active (non filtered) element in a Pivot Table (excluding the column labels and grand totals)?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I was expecting the fields to be "Sum of Reg Hrs.", "Sum of Reg OT Hrs.", ... , "Sum of SNWH NSD Hrs."

But what I got was `MsgBox pf` shows "Values"

`Msgbox pi` shows "Sum of Reg Hrs.", "Sum of Reg OT Hrs.", ... , "Sum of SNWH NSD Hrs."

But ideally, I want `pi` to be the items of each column. Is there another method to do so?

```
Sub test()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("N-MR Hours Summary").PivotTables("N-MR Hours Summary")

For Each pf In pt.ColumnFields
    MsgBox pf
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        MsgBox pi
    Next pi
Next pf

End Sub()
```

[image]

Also, it should only include, the active cells (non filtered cells), but I realized even the filtered cells are iterated about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table has a `PivotRowAxis` (vertical) and a `PivotColumnAxis` (horizontal).
They each consist of one or more `PivotLines`.
Following screenshot explains both axis and their `PivotLines` with `PivotLineCells`.

[image: PivotLine Explanation]

In your example, each `PivotColumnAxis.PivotLine` only has 1 `PivotLineCell`.
The `PivotLine.PivotLineType` can be used to identify rows or columns with regular values, sub totals, grand total or completely blank lines:

[image: PivotLineType Explanation]

As your columns only consist of `DataFields` (no dedicated `ColumnFields`), you can loop over `PivotColumnAxis.PivotLine(i).PivotLineCells(1).PivotField` to get the vertical `DataRange` of each column:

[image: PivotLineCell with PivotField and its DataRange]

Here's the code for it:

```
Private Sub ColumnByColumn()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pl As PivotLine
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim c As Range

    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    For Each pl In pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines
        If pl.LineType = xlPivotLineRegular Then
            Set pf = pl.PivotLineCells(1).PivotField
            If pf.Orientation = xlDataField Then
                Debug.Print pf.Caption,
                For Each c In pf.DataRange.Cells
                    Debug.Print c.Value,
                Next c
                Debug.Print
            End If
        End If
    Next pl
End Sub
```

---

Further hints:

Your pivottable only contains `DataFields` (no explicit `ColumnFields`), therefore the pivotfield's name is returned as "Values".

Unfortunately it's never simple to loop over all *visible* pivotitems, as a simple loop over all of them also returns the invisible (filtered) items. Even `PivotField.VisibleItems.Count` always returns the same value as `PivotField.PivotItems.Count`.

`PivotLine.LineType` is in your case always `xlPivotLineRegular` (It could also be `xlPivotLineBlank`, `xlPivotLineSubtotal` or `xlPivotLineGrandTotal` if you would have blank columns, subtotal columns or grand total columns).

Comment: This works I spent quite a while trying to figure this out but was not successful in coming close

Comment: I've been trying to understand the code and how the logic behind the methods work. But I am having a hard time understanding what `pl.LineType` refers to. What exactly is a "Line" object. I cannot seem to grasp in my head how `pl.LineType = xlPivotLineRegular` looks like.

Comment: And if a single column is addressed as a `PivotLine`, then `pl.PivotLineCells()` should return each cell in the column, but in this case, only `pl.PivotLineCells(1).PivotField` works and only returns the column headers. Things like `pl.PivotLineCells(2).PivotField` will not return the 2nd cell of that row but will error.

Comment: Yes, it's complicated. I added some screenshots with explanations to demonstrate it :)

Comment: It is really complicated without this I would be really, really stuck trying to figure things out

Comment: `pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1).PivotLineCells(1).PivotField.DataRange.Cells(i)` when I experimented with this line, it also includes cells outside the PivotTable's data range (grand totals and cells outside the Pivot Table) when I set the `Cells(i)` to the coordinates of the cell. However doing `For each test in pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1).PivotLineCells(1).PivotField.DataRange` will ony loop through all the data elements under the column field and before the grand totals as you said